# Citizen science projects in Matter Modeling

Tags: one-topic-per-answer, high-performance-computing

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volunteer_computing),

> Volunteer computing is a type of distributed computing in which people donate their computers' unused resources to a research-oriented project

An example of a volunteer computing project is [SETI@home](https://setiathome.berkeley.edu/) (for extraterrestrial intelligence search, -hibernating now-).

**Can people here please explain the such projects in Matter Modeling?**

Active:

- [Folding@home](https://setiathome.berkeley.edu/) [[link to answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1835/5)]
- [Rosetta@home](https://boinc.bakerlab.org/rosetta/) [[link to answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/6484/653)]
- Cleanmobility.now
- RNA World
- CAS@home
- [ScienceAtHome](https://www.scienceathome.org/about-us/) [[link to answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1840/5)]

Inactive:

- Genome@home
- POEM@Home
- SIMAP
- DENIS@Home
- USPEX@Home
- eOn
- Leiden Classical
- QMC@Home
- Magnetism@home
- SLinCA
- DrugDiscovery@home

Answer (score 10):

## Folding@home

**Research area**: Protein folding and protein structure prediction (mainly for studying diseases)
**Initiated by**: Vijay Pande (while at Stanford University)
**Present leader**: Greg Bowman (Washington University in St. Louis)
**Active**: October 2000 to Present 
**Supported OS**: Windows, Mac, Linux
**Supported hardware types**: CPU, GPU, PlayStation 3 (in past), Sony Xperia smartphone (in past)
**Peak FLOPS**: 2.43 exa-FLOPS on 12 April 2020 (claimed to reach exascale) 
**Resulted in**: 220+ publications

Answer (score 8):

## ScienceAtHome

**Research area**: Science-based games that generate real data for researchers. The original and most well known project is *Quantum Moves (2)*, which is meant to provide new strategies for Quantum Optimal Control through user input in the game.
**Initiated/Led by**: Jacob F. Sherson, physics professor at Aarhus University.
**Active**: 2012-Present
**Operating Systems**: Windows, Mac
**Resulted in**: 35 publications as of 7/28/2020

Comment: +1. How did you find this? It was not in here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_distributed_computing_projects

Comment: @NikeDattani I had actually remembered trying out the Quantum Moves game a few years ago.

Comment: cool :) I added the URL to it in the question. Otherwise we could make a category for URL in the answer. I find making the "header" to be a link, is a bit less aesthetically pleasing because the desktop Chrome browser puts a fat underline below hyperlinks (whereas the Android Chrome browser just makes hyperlinks a pretty blue, without any underline, which would be okay if this is how the desktop version displayed hyperlinks).

Answer (score 7):

## Rosetta@home

**Research area**: Protein structure prediction and disease related research (Alzheimer, HIV, COVID-19, etc.), but also a testing framework for new methods in structural bioinformatics
**Initiated by**: [University of Washington](https://cruizbran.medium.com/rosetta-home-the-origin-786e8c1171c4)
**Present leader**: Baker laboratory (University of Washington)
**Active**: October 2005 to Present 
**Supported OS**: Windows, Mac, Linux, Android
**Supported hardware types**: Anything supported by [BOINC](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/)
**Peak FLOPS**: 1.7 petaFLOPS on 28 March 2020 
**Resulted in**: Multiple publications, played a role in the development of [NL-201](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NL-201). Some of the results are used as the basis for Folding@home projects by providing the most likely structure, where Folding@home will verify the results and add details on molecule shape.

Uses the same Berkeley Open Infrastructure for Network Computing (BOINC) system as SETI@home (extraterrestrial), LHC@home (fundamental physics) and Einstein@home (astrophysics, pulsars), making it run on almost any CPU and GPU (some run it on a  Raspberry Pi). With a mobile user-interface, you can keep track of your progress from a mobile device as well.